# IIS/DB - Application pool vs Config file (connection string) - Who wins?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, database-connection

If I am running a web server 1.0.0.1 supporting an IIS .NET 4.0 site and trying to connect to another 1.0.0.2 server running MS-SQL (Database). For the connection between the two, is it the Application Pool's user or the Web.config's ConnectionString the active communication between the two systems? A few examples:

Scenario 1 -- (WIN Config?) *This one is IMPORTANT*
Application Pool User: Network Service
Application Pool Load User Profile: FALSE
Web.config Connection String: DOMAIN\User

Scenario 2 -- (WIN App Pool?) 
Application Pool User: DOMAIN\User
Application Pool Load User Profile: TRUE
Web.config Connection String: Integrated Service=TRUE

Scenario 3 -- (WIN IIS_USER?) 
Application Pool User: ApplicationPoolIdentity
Application Pool Load User Profile: FALSE
Web.config Connection String: Integrated Service=TRUE

Finally...I would theorize that the CLR is running the IIS_USER (unless App Pool is DOMAIN account) while the connect to SQL it is using the Web.Config's Connection String information. However I have people saying I am wrong about this so I am really confused.

Comment: Whatever is specified in the connection string, wins. How else could it be? If  Integrated Security is set in the connection string, then the current user is of course used. If running in IIS then the current user will be the one set by the Application Pool.

Comment: How else could this be? ...no idea and honestly I felt stupid asking this but I had two Sr. DB guys tell me off. Seeing as they've been in the industry longer and were VERY amendment about this stance I honestly doubted myself a little. ...and honestly a sure bit confused. Thanks, I honestly do feel better

Comment: After reading that, I insist whomever reads this next takes a shot for every time I said honestly.... you're welcome ;)

Comment: I suggest that you go humbly try to learn from the DB guys. Be suitably contrite, and they might explain it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way of telling for sure, is to lock one of the accounts out from connecting to the database server.